# Каким методом лучше всего шифровать записываемые данные в файл?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шифрование

Каким методом лучше всего шифровать записываемые данные в файл?

Пишу пет-проект **Держателя данных банковских карт** в виде консольного приложения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не бывает методов, которые "лучше всего". Есть методы которые хорошо подходят под задачу, есть методы которые подходят хуже. Есть которые вообще не подходят. Чтобы сказать что-то в вашем случае, нужно знать задачу.

Comment: А причём здесь язык?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как можно сделать:

1. Делаешь рандомизатор с привязкой генерации ко времени (ctime), но ограничь её ASCII кодировкой или той кодировкой в которой работаешь (чтоб не выйти за ее пределы).
2. Ту строку что тебе нужно зашифровать разбиваешь на символы (или посимвольно проходишься циклом)
3. С помощью функции генерации чисел к символу добавляешь значение, что оно сгенерировало и записываешь в новую строку (типа 'f' + 44)
4. Сохраняй при этом то сгенерированное число (это и будет часть ключа, для каждого символа свое рандомизированное число-ключ)
5. Полная последовательность из сгенерированных чисел и будет ключом
6. Новая полученная строка - зашифрована.
7. Теперь для расшифровки нужен ключ и строка.

PS: Алгоритм самого шифрования может быть любым не обязательно сложение.

Comment: Иван, Спасибо большое) Пойду применять!